# sInfo en puglin datatable no funciona para mostrar de n a n entradas?

Tags: jquery

al momento de mostrar los resultados de la datatable de *START* a *END* no funciona y tampoco la paginación esta comportandose correctamente pues me deja elegir cualquier pagina incluso si no tiene datos, ayudaaa!!! 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
table.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                .withOption("ajax", {
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'Usuario/GetAllUsers'
                })
                .withDataProp("data")
                .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
                .withDOM('<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp')
                .withOption("createdRow", createdRow)
                .withOption('serverSide', true)
                .withButtons([
                    { extend: 'copy', className: 'btn-sm' },
                    { extend: 'csv', className: 'btn-sm' },
                    { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn-sm', title: 'XLS-File' },
                    { extend: 'pdf', className: 'btn-sm', title: $('title').text() },
                    { extend: 'print', className: 'btn-sm' }
                ])
                .withLanguage({
                    "sEmptyTable": "No existen Usuarios",
                    "sInfo": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ entradas",
                    "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando de 0 a 0 de 0 entradas",
                    "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrando de un total de _MAX_ entradas)",
                    "sInfoPostFix": "",
                    "sInfoThousands": ",",
                    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrando _MENU_ entradas",
                    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                    "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
                    "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                    "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron coincidencias",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sFirst": "Primero",
                        "sLast": "Ultimo",
                        "sNext": "Siguiente",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                    },
                    "oAria": {
                        "sSortAscending": ": ascendiente",
                        "sSortDescending": ": descendiente"
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Deberias de incluir la respuesta que mandas en `GetAllUsers`

Comment: Intentaste colocando "info": "Página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_" en vez de sInfo?

Comment: @alanfcm muchas gracias es correcto, no estaba mandando la respuesta de records total y filtered gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi error, era no retornar desde el controller MVC recordstotal y recordsfiltered

Comment: Hola david canche, me alegro que encontraras el problema. ¿Cómo hiciste o qué parte del código cambiaste para retornar `recordstotal` y `recordsfiltered` desde el controlador MVC? Deberías editar la respuesta para añadir esa información, que podría ser útil para otros usuarios con problemas similares.